# Check whether A and B exists for the given values AorB and APlusB

Tags: algorithm, bit-manipulation

Problem Statement:

You are given two non-negative integers: the longs pairOr and pairSum.

Determine whether it is possible that for two non-negative integers A and B we have both:

- A or B = pairOr
- A + B = pairSum

Above, "or" denotes the bitwise-or operator.

Return True if we can find such A and B, and False if not.

My Algorithm goes like this:

I've taken the equation:  A | B = X and A + B =Y,

Now after substituting A's value from 2nd Equation, (Y-B) | B= X.

I'm going to traverse from 0 till Y (in place of B) to check if the above equation is true.

Code Snippet:

```
boolean isPossible(long orAandB,long plusAandB) {

    for(long i=0;i<=plusAandB;i++) {
        if(((plusAandB-i)|i)==orAandB ){
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
```

It will give TLE if the value of plusAndB is of number `10^18`. Could you please help me optimize?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the full iteration, giving O(N). There's a way to do it in O(logN).

But completely solving the problem for you takes away most of the fun... ;-), so here's the main clue:

Your equation `(Y-B) | B= X` is one great observation, and the second is to have a look at this equation bit by bit, starting from the right (so you don't have to worry about borrow-bits in the first place). Which last-bit combinations of Y, X, and B can make your equation true? And if you found a B bit, how do you continue recursively with the higher bits (don't forget that subtraction may need a borrow)? I hope you remember the rules for subtracting binary numbers.

And keeping in mind that the problem only asks for true or false, not for any specific A or B value, can save you exponential complexity.